# Animate the drawing of an MKPolyline on MKMapView

Tags: mapkit, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I’ve got an `MKMapView` to animate a line by adding a line, removing it, adding a minor segment and re-adding it to the map. However, this puts a lot of overhead on the phone and doesn’t look the best. I noticed Google Maps and Uber have cleanly animated lines for showing routes that run smoothly no matter what the length or route type. Does anyone have any suggestions for a solution which is less energy-draining and looks cleaner?

Thanks, SebO.

Answer (score 0):

1. An array of coordinates will be needed. If you have only beginning and end coordinates, get array of coordinates using below code

   ```
   func getPointsOnRoute(from: CLLocation?, to: CLLocation?, on mapView: MKMapView?) -> [CLLocation]? {
   let NUMBER_OF_PIXELS_TO_SKIP: Int = 120
   //lower number will give a more smooth animation, but will result in more layers
   var ret = [Any]()

   var fromPoint: CGPoint? = nil
   if let aCoordinate = from?.coordinate {
       fromPoint = mapView?.convert(aCoordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
   }
   var toPoint: CGPoint? = nil
   if let aCoordinate = to?.coordinate {
       toPoint = mapView?.convert(aCoordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
   }
   let allPixels = getAllPoints(from: fromPoint!, to: toPoint!)
   var i = 0
   while i < (allPixels?.count)! {
       let pointVal = allPixels![i] as? NSValue
       ret.append(point(toLocation: mapView, from: (pointVal?.cgPointValue)!)!)
       i += NUMBER_OF_PIXELS_TO_SKIP
   }
   ret.append(point(toLocation: mapView, from: toPoint!)!)
   return ret as? [CLLocation] }
   ```
2. Having array of coordinates add rendering of the overlays in MKMapViewDelegate’s delegate method — `mapView(_:rendererFor:)`.

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
   guard let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline else {
           return MKOverlayRenderer()
       }

       let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline)
       polylineRenderer.strokeColor = .black
       polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 2
       return polylineRenderer
   }
   mapView.addOverlay(polyline) // add it to mapview
   ```

   3. render the polyline in small segments to create the animation effect

   ```
   var drawingTimer: Timer?
   // ....// Somewhere in your View Controller
   func animate(route: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], duration: TimeInterval, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
           guard route.count > 0 else { return }
           var currentStep = 1
           let totalSteps = route.count
           let stepDrawDuration = duration/TimeInterval(totalSteps)
           var previousSegment: MKPolyline?

           drawingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: stepDrawDuration, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
               guard let self = self else {
                   // Invalidate animation if we can't retain self
                   timer.invalidate()
                   completion?()
                   return
               }

               if let previous = previousSegment {
                   // Remove last drawn segment if needed.
                   self.mapView.removeOverlay(previous)
                   previousSegment = nil
               }

               guard currentStep < totalSteps else {
                   // If this is the last animation step...
                   let finalPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: route, count: route.count)
                   self.mapView.addOverlay(finalPolyline)
                   // Assign the final polyline instance to the class property.
                   self.polyline = finalPolyline
                   timer.invalidate()
                   completion?()
                   return
               }

               // Animation step.
               // The current segment to draw consists of a coordinate array from 0 to the 'currentStep' taken from the route.
               let subCoordinates = Array(route.prefix(upTo: currentStep))
               let currentSegment = MKPolyline(coordinates: subCoordinates, count: subCoordinates.count)
               self.mapView.addOverlay(currentSegment)

               previousSegment = currentSegment
               currentStep += 1
           }
       }
   ```